# Django - how can I set default image for an ImageField model

Tags: django, url, django-queryset, imagefield

I have an imagefield type for my model

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    face_image = models.ImageField()
```

the question is if I have an image in static, how can i assign it to this imagefield ? if not it could be from a url the image, how can i assign to this imagefield

For example this would be how I would create the object, what should be assigned to face_image_obj ?

```
attendance_new = Attendance(face_image = face_image_obj)                                                       
attendance_new.save()
```